# Unable to do POST request using C# code using authentication

Tags: c#, rest, http, post

I am using below code to do a POST request on a url.

```
namespace ConsoleAppPost
{
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace HttpClientStatus
    {
        class Program
        {
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                using var client = new HttpClient();

                var result = await client.PostAsync("https://XXXX/api/XXX/XX/XXX/xyz", HttpContent content);
                Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

But ,i am getting below error:

No overload for method PostAsync takes 1 argument

I also want to use username and password as authentication to do POST request in the code.
Please help me.

Comment: you're not passing any data into the second PostAsync param..

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies here

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("https://XXXX/api/XXX/XX/XXX/xyz", HttpContent content);
```

You are passing type `HttpContent content` as parameter and NOT the data instead?

You need to do something like this

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", "<value>"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "<value>"),
});
var result = await client.PostAsync("https://XXXX/api/XXX/XX/XXX/xyz", content);
```

Comment: Now, I am getting below error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'KeyValuePair<,>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @PenguinTech use `System.Collections.Generic` namespace

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now.   But i am unable to print any response on command line though i use Console.Readline :   var result = await client.PostAsync("XXXXX", content);
                    Console.ReadLine();

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also are you expecting from your post request?

Comment: I am not getting any error. In the console ,i am not getting any output printed . I am expecting the response similar to when i do the post request from browser .

Comment: I am sorry without going into further details of what your API is doing I can't comment on the output. You have to investigate that part. The original question was on `Post request` and I have guided you in what seems to be the right path.

Comment: I am using PostAsync for POST api call to Create a ticket in a web application : await client.PostAsync("https://xxxxxx/xxxx/xx/", content);